# ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers on sharepoint online: how to use it

Tags: search, managed-property, content-search-web-part

I have a simple Content Search web part where I want to display the number of views of items.

I have seen that my preferred property has got the query property unchecked. I tried to insert it into RefinableInt but I was not able to map it.

Of the list of properties with views, I have seen ViewsRecent has the query ticked. I have used it but it does not display.

What am I doing wrong?